# Matching a list of names to files when the names are reversed

Tags: python, pandas, filenames, file-copying

I have a .csv with a column called 'Name' listing individuals in `Firstname MI. Lastname` format:

- Stephen A. Johnson.

And I have a folder full of files made by these individuals in `lastnamefirstname` format:

- johnsonstephen_78938

Using the list of names I need to find the files that match and save those files to a separate folder.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You're working with strings, so just straightforward: read the csv, split the names, get the first and last, concatenate them,...

Comment: it would be great if you could provide a reproducible example of what you mean.

Comment: also, is there any meaning behind the digits at the end of the files? Are they junk or important

Comment: The numbers are identifiers but not important for my purposes. So junk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Model

Let's prepare some space to model:

```
# necessary part
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy     # consider copy2 as alternative if metadata should be copied as well

# for demonstration purpose
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory 
from os import listdir
from io import StringIO

data = '''
Stephen A. Johnson
Stephen B. Johnson
Albert J. Reiß
'''
csv_source = StringIO(data)

source = TemporaryDirectory(); src = Path(source.name)
destin = TemporaryDirectory(); dst = Path(destin.name)

filenames = [
    'johnsonstephen_30',
    'johnsonstephen_40',
    'reissalbert_50',     # should be copied with `casefold` and ignored with `lower`
    'gibberish_10',       # should be ignored
]

for file in filenames:
    (src/file).touch()
```

Now the main part. There's at least one pitfall: `casefold` versus `lower` when applied to the original names. This may influence on the file names selected and should be consciously resolved on your side. I use `casefold` and the name `"Reiß"` to demonstrate how it might appear.

```
# read the sequence of names
person = pd.read_csv(csv_source, header=None).squeeze()

# preparing name stems
ersatz = (
    person
    .str.casefold()     # not identical to `lower`, select one according to naming policy
    .str.split()
    .str[::-2]          # it won't work if the middle name doesn't exist.
    .str.join('')
    .unique()
)

# copying files of interest
for name in ersatz:
    for file in src.rglob(f'{name}_*'):
        copy(file, dst)
```

Check the result and clean up the space:

```
print(f'Source:      {listdir(src)}')
print(f'Destination: {listdir(dst)}')

source.cleanup()
destin.cleanup()
```

Expected output:

```
Source:      ['gibberish_1234', 'johnsonstephen_40', 'johnsonstephen_30', 'reissalbert_50']
Destination: ['johnsonstephen_40', 'johnsonstephen_30', 'reissalbert_50']
```

*P.S. Alternatively, when loading a csv file, we can interpret whitespace characters as a delimiter:*

```
# read the sequence of names
person = pd.read_csv(
    csv_source, 
    header=None, 
    delim_whitespace=True, 
    usecols=[0,2],
    names=['firstname','lastname'],
)
ersatz = person['lastname'].str.casefold() + person['firstname'].str.casefold()
```

### Real life

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy     

# declare csv-file and source/destination folders
source = 'path/to/folder/with/files'
destination = 'folder/to/copy/files/into'
csv_source = 'path/to/comma_separated_data_with_column_Name.csv'

# main script
src = Path(source)
dst = Path(destination)

person = read_csv(csv_source)['Name'].squeeze()
ersatz = (
    person
    .str.casefold()
    .str.split()
    .pipe(lambda seq: seq.str[-1] + seq.str[0])    # rely only on first and last name
    .unique()
)

for name in ersatz:
    for file in src.rglob(f'{name}_*'):
        copy(file, dst)
```

Comment: Hi. I've reproduced your code in Jupyter and I get the expected output. But I haven't used some of these packages and am confused about where to edit this for the path to my folders. Would it be possible to put comments where I need to input this, please? Thank you!

Comment: @Linter see updates in **Real life** part

Comment: I'm noticing that it fails if there the name has a 'Jr.' or 'Sr.' or 'III' as part of the name. Or if the name is hyphenated or a double last name. But I think I can work on that.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the program list the names which were *not* matched to a file?

Comment: @Linter We could `pd.merge(..., how='outer')` on two tables. One is names with stems (I called them _ersatz_). The other is filenames with stems, sort of `filenames = pd.DataFrame([(f.name.split('_', 1)[0], f.name) for f in Path(source).glob('*') if '_' in f.name], columns=['ersatz', 'filename'])`. Then we can see null on non matching files and names.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet demonstrates how to compare name in differece format.

```py
nameStr = 'Stephen A. Johnson'.split()
nameFile = 'johnsonstephen_78938'

if ( (nameStr[-1]+nameStr[0]).lower() == nameFile.split("_")[0].lower() ):
  print('match')
else:
  print('mismatch')
```

---

Let's assume

- csv file as below

```
Name,Age
Stephen A. Johnson,34
Mike Jackson,22
```

- source file path: D:\temp\src
- destination file path: D:\temp\dest

```py
import pandas as pd
import pathlib as Path
import shutil as sh
path = Path.Path(r'D:\temp\namelist.csv')
file_path_src = Path.Path(r'D:\temp\src')
file_path_dest = Path.Path(r'D:\temp\dest')
files = {}
# iterate through the files in the source folder
for file in file_path_src.iterdir():
    # check the file name has "_"
    if file.name.count("_") == 1:
        sname = file.name.split("_")[0].lower()
        if sname in files:
            files[sname].append(file)
        else:
            files[sname] = [file]
print(files)
# load csv file
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=0)
# create destination folder if not exists
if not file_path_dest.exists():
    file_path_dest.mkdir()
# iterate through the names in the csv file
for name in df['Name'].tolist():
    name_arr = name.split(" ")
    namekey = (name_arr[-1]+name_arr[0]).lower()
    # chech if the name is in the files dict
    if namekey in files:
        for file in files[namekey]:
            print('Copying file: ', file )
            # copy the file to the destination folder
            sh.copy(file, file_path_dest)
print('Done')
```

Comment: Wow: I had to update the absolute paths since I'm using linux, but this *almost* works. It moved a single file. The file corresponds to the final name in the namelist. The other 105 files that should have moved did not. Ideas?

Comment: The code in last post is not the final version. I have updated the code. Please try it again.

Comment: No joy. When the print(files) runs it only returns '{}'. It seems to successfully move a single file.

Comment: Please make sure `file_path_src` is exist and the files name with one '-'.  `if file_path_src.exists():
    print('Source folder exists')`